# OnPropertyChange not firing in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm

Hi I'm working through a Todo tutorial on Xamarin Forms and MVVM using Visual Studio Community 2022. I'm a newbie at both C# and Xamarin. The app displays a list of items. OnPropertyChange is used in TodoViewModel.cs and is supposed to update the form page title with the contents of the selected item when an item is clicked. But nothing happens and the execution does not stop on a breakpoint inside of the OnPropertyChange event handler. So the event handler is not getting called for some reason.
Here's the OnPropertyChanged method that doesn't execute:

```
    public TodoItem SelectedItem {  get => _selectedItem;
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            PageTitle = value?.Name;
            OnPropertyChanged("PageTitle");
        }
    }
```

I've included all the code and would love some help.

**App.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Todo.App">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**App.xml.cs**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Todo
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(  new TodoView());
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**TodoView.xml.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Todo
{
    public partial class TodoView : ContentPage
    {
        public TodoView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new TodoViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

**TodoView.xml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Todo.TodoView"
             Title = "{Binding PageTitle}">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                  SelectedItem="Binding SelectedItem">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**TodoViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Todo
{
    public class TodoViewModel: BindableObject
    {
        private TodoItem _selectedItem;
        public TodoViewModel()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<TodoItem>(TodoItem.GetTodoItems());
        }
        public ObservableCollection<TodoItem> Items { get; set; }
        public string PageTitle { get; set; }
        public TodoItem SelectedItem {  get => _selectedItem;
            set
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                PageTitle = value?.Name;
                OnPropertyChanged("PageTitle");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**TodoItems.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Todo
{
    public class TodoItem
    {
        public TodoItem(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Completed { get; set; }

        public static IEnumerable<TodoItem> GetTodoItems()
        {
            return new List<TodoItem>
            {
                new TodoItem ("Go to work"),
                new TodoItem ("Buy bananas"),
                new TodoItem ("Milk"),
                new TodoItem ("Dexcom"),
                new TodoItem ("Test strips")

            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: to start with, `SelectedItem="Binding SelectedItem"` is missing the brackets `{}`

Comment: @Jason Thanks for spotting that; it worked If you repost your comment as an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the `{}` in your binding expression

```
SelectedItem="Binding SelectedItem"
```

should be

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
```